# Getting Out of memory exception for using gate to process document

Tags: java, nlp

I am processing large size documents having 50000 to 60000 characters(a corpus of 1000 documents). After processing 800-850 documents I'm getting out of memory exception. Jprofiler is pointing to code calling gate method as the method consuming maximum memory

**Error line:**

```
List<Annotation> sortedTokens = new ArrayList<Annotation>(document.getAnnotations().get(ANNIEConstants.TOKEN_ANNOTATION_TYPE).get(nChunkStart,nChunkEnd));
```

though I'm deleting corpus and document, like:

```
Factory.deleteResource(corpus);
Factory.deleteResource(document);
```

Still I'm getting same out of memory exception.

Comment: How much memory are you allocating?

Comment: I'm allocating 3gb memory

Comment: I don't have experience with GATE, but 3GB does not sound like much for a chunker. Try allocating some more.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced similar issues, are you making the GATE window visible. Cause that takes up significant memory and has many memory leaks.